# Reading local BSON file in Javascript

Tags: javascript, bson

I have an HTML 5 game. I'm using webpack/typescript for development.

There is some data I have which I was including by using `require` like the following

```
    const dataJson = require('scripts/data/data.json');
```

I would like to do the equivalent, except with bson. I tried the naive approach of doing something like this

```
    const dataJson = require('scripts/data/data.bson');
```

but this of course fails since there is no loader (won't compile with `currently no loaders are configured to process this file.`).

I'd like to then include the file locally, load the file and then deserialize the bson. Or I'd like to embed the `bson` like when using `require`. This is some tool generated data, so it will be in a data file.

I haven't been able to figure it out. I've tried the following. But this results in the `result` containing either the `bits` of `File` or what looks like the content type (if done as `readAsDataURL`).

What I have tried

```
    const file = new File(['data'], 'assets/data.bson', { type: 'application/bson' });
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload=(theFile) => {
        if (theFile.target) {
            console.log(theFile.target.result);
        }

    } ;
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    //reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
```

What is the correct method to load a local binary file? Presumably, once I have the data, I can just call `deserialize` from the `bson` package.

Okay, I'm adding some corrections here. 
My method to read the files is wrong. I know understand `File` will actually create a file. So when this is passed to `FileReader` it gets the value of the both `bits` passed in.

I have since discovered I can get the local files 2 ways. I can use `XMLHttpRequest` as well as the `raw-loader` loader.

However once I do this. I cannot seem to convert the contents into JSON using `bson`. Any variant of `deserialize`, `serialize`, `parse`, or `stringify` has some issue.

Does anyone happen to have the correct method to convert the BSON contents into either a Javascript Object?

Note that the BSON is generated from python using `pymongo`. My code to generate the BSON is the following.

```
            with open(args.output_bson, 'wb') as fp:
                encoded = bson.encode(data_meta.to_dict())
                fp.write(encoded)
```

`to_dict` is a dictionary. I output both the JSON (using `json`) and BSON.

I also tested the file with `bsondump` and it does indeed convert to JSON. So it does appear the file I've loaded is valid.

Comment: have you figured this out?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [bson](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bson)

then call:

```
BSON.deserialize(theFile.target.result);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately this doesn't work. I've updated my question with newer findings.